# Calculate $\sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \int_{-1}^1 f dg$ for $g=x^2$.

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum, stieltjes-integral

The following is from Bruckner's Real Analysis book (Ex.12:8.3):

> Let $g(x)=x^2$ on $[−1, 1]$, and let $\mathcal{F} = {\{f \in \mathcal{C}[−1,1] : |f(x)| ≤ 5 \ \text{for all} \ x∈[−1,1]}\}$. Calculate $\sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \int_{-1}^1 f dg$.

I don't know any method of solving this, but I write some primitive thoughts. The integral becomes $\int_{-1}^1 2x f(x) dx$. $\sup$ cannot be for $f$ an even function of $x$. The integrand is bounded by $10|x|$. Because integration is on $[-1,1]$ thus the higher power polynomial the less value of the integral...

Comment: Why not choose a sequence of functions that tend to $f(x) = 5\text{sign}(x)$?

Comment: $g(x)$ is of bounded variation on $[-1,1]$ and so is the difference of two nondecreasing  monotone functions. For example $x^2=x^2\mathbb{1}(x\geq1)-(-x^2\mathbb{f}(x\leq0))=\phi(x)-\psi(x)$, then $\int_If\,dg=\int_I f\,d\phi -\int_I f\,\psi$. Then the obvious choice $f(x)=5\operatorname{sign}(x)$ may be worth trying.

Answer (score 1):

From exercise 12:8.2, we know that
$$ \left | \int_a^b f dg    \right|\leq  \|f\|_\infty \|g\|$$

For the current case, $\|g\| = V(g, [-1, 1]) = 2$  and $\|f\|_\infty =5$. So we have
$$ \left | \int_{-1}^1 f dg    \right|\leq  10$$
that means
$$ -10 \leq  \int_{-1}^1 f dg    \leq  10 \tag{1}$$

Now, you have already shown that $\int_{-1}^1 f dg = \int_{-1}^1 2x f(x) dx$. So, if we pick $f(x) = 5 \ \text{sgn}(x)$, we have

$$\int_{-1}^1 f dg = \int_{-1}^1 2x f(x) dx = \int_{-1}^1 10 |x| dx =10 \tag{2}$$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$, we have that $\sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \int_{-1}^1 f dg = 10$.

**Remark**: In the current case, to calculate  $V(g, [-1, 1])$, note that $g$ is monotone on $[-1,0]$ and monotone on $[0,1]$, So
$$V(g, [-1, 0])= |g(0) - g(-1)| = 1 $$
and
$$V(g, [0, 1])= |g(1) - g(0)| = 1 $$
Finally,
$$V(g, [-1, 1]) =V(g, [-1, 0])+V(g, [0, 1])=2$$

Comment: (I deleted my question in this comment bc I found the solution)

Comment: Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @L.G. You are always welcome. Anyway, I added a remark to my answer showing in detail that $V(g,[−1,1])=2$.